Using `Filling` in a plot changes the font of the tick marks?
If I evaluate the following code (in Mma 14.0 on an Apple silicon 2024 macbook running macos 14.6.1 (23G93))
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]

I get the following two graphs:

The font changed, and in fact even the resolution. It looks like I opened a portal to 1995 through which plots are coming in… This is surely not intended? Is there a way to sidestep this?

Works with MMA 14.1

(1) When posting a new question, please do not use the [bugs] tag; it should be added when it is confirmed there is a bug. (2) In suspected cases of bugs, it is also important to know which operating system you are using. Please edit the question and include this. (3) There has been similar issues like this on SE before. Please see #282025 and try with the option ""HardwareAntialiasingQuality".

@Domen, well, it is obviously a bug, isn't it?

@MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, please look at the description of the bugs tag.

There. I have removed the tag. I hope this helps. When someone can confirm it is a biug, they can readd it.

Yeah, I can see that happening if the antialiasing quality level slider in the preferences dialog is not all the way to the right.  One way to "sidestep" this is to specFillingStyle->color_of_choice without an Opacity value.  i.e., it is a solid color.

I cannot reproduce your problem.
MacBook Pro (Apple M2 Pro) macOS Sonoma 14.6.1
$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]


